# NodeJS Mongoose Data Structure Design Referencing Multiple Todo items to Projects with Categories

Tags: node.js, mongoose, database-design, database-schema, mongoose-schema

I'm working with reactjs and using mongodb/mongoose as my database. I have a project model and category model, and was wondering if this is the correct way of doing relationships if I want to have multiple todo items and categorizing it for each project?

project model:

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
    items: [
      {
        categoires: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'categories'
        },
        name: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

category model

```
const categorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    project: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "project",
    },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
  }
);
```

Is my schema referencing correct? Should I have separated the items array into another model and then try to reference the items into the project model?